# .hover fade image out, fade new image in. On exit return to original image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my company logo appearing in the footer of my site, when the user hovers over the footer I want the image `logo.png` to fade out, then `biglogo.png` to fade in - in its place.

When the user moves the cursor away from #footer I want `logo.png` to fade back in.

```
<div id="footer">
                <div id="logowrap">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="active" />
                    <img src="images/biglogo.png" alt="" />
                </div>
</div>
```

I've tried so many things but dont seem to be able to get the logic right, I end up with flashing images, images that fadeout when I want them to fade in.

Any help greatfully received (I'm pulling my hair out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#logowrap").hover(function() {
    $("#logowrap img:first").stop().fadeOut("fast",function() {
      $("#logowrap img:last").stop().fadeIn("fast");  
    });
  }, function() {
    $("#logowrap img:last").stop().fadeOut("fast",function() {
      $("#logowrap img:first").stop().fadeIn("fast");  
    });
  });
```

It fades the first image and when finished starts fading the other back in, then does the reverse on hover out.  You can use `$(this)` a bit more, but this looks cleaner for this specific case I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="footer">
                <div id="logowrap">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="active" />
                    <img src="images/biglogo.png" alt="active_big" />
                </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#active').bind('mouseout',function(){
```

$('#active').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#active').attr('src','images/logo.png');
    )};

```
$('#active_big').bind('mouseover',function(){
```

$('#active').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#active_big').attr('src','images/biglogo.png');
    )};

```
});
```

Should work fine for you